# JQuery Hover only Showing the First Hidden Div for Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am pulling titles and descriptions out of a database, and I want the descriptions to popup when the title is hovered over.  For some reason, the same description keeps popping up when I hover over any of the links.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Here is the php:

```
<?php foreach ($updateInfo['updates'] as $update) {
    echo "</td><td>". $update['fldLeadText'].' <a class="small popper" href="">Read more...</a> <div id="pop">
          <p>'.$update['fldBodyText'].'</p>
          </div>';
    ...
```

The jquery:

```js
$(function() {
    $('a.popper').hover(function() {
        $('#pop').toggle();
    });
});
```

And the CSS:

```css
#pop{
    display              : none;
    position             : absolute;
    z-index              : 99999;
    padding              : 10px;
    background           : #ffffff;
    border               : 1px solid #A2ADBC;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem may be with $("#pop").toggle(). Is there only one popup? If so, wouldn't you need to set the description and location on it?

Comment: I'm assuming the id is potentially repeated.

Comment: instead of `$('#pop').toggle();` use `$(this).find('.pop');` and in your HTML instead of `id="pop"` use `class="pop"`, also in CSS use class instead of ID

Answer (score 1):

When adding elements in a loop AND giving them an ID, you run the risk of duplicating the IDS which will cause this problem.

IDs must be unique, so you can't reuse the same one on the same page. But you can reuse classes.

Change `id="pop"` to `class="pop"`

Change this in your jquery:

```
   $('a.popper').hover(function() {
        $(this).next(".pop").toggle();
    });
```

change `#pop` in your css to `.pop`

Comment: Yup. The most common mistake coders do initially is repeat the `id` in loops by accident. Simple problem, easy fix!

Answer (score -1):

You can try use the title attribute in html only this:

```
<td title="title for hover"> text </td>
```